# How to get apropos to show only executable programs/shell commands?

Tags: grep, man, documentation, apropos

Most of the times when I use `apropos` I don't care about system calls, library calls etc — I'm just trying to find a command I forgot the name of. Is there a way to trim down the output of `apropos` to show only executables and commands (section 1 of the manual) and filter out everything else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you’re using [the `man-db` version of `apropos`](https://nongnu.org/man-db/), you can specify the section you’re interested in with the `-s` option:

```
apropos -s 1 read
```

If you want to include administrative commands,

```
apropos -s 1,8 read
```

From `man apropos`:

> ```
> -s list, --sections=list, --section=list
> ```
>
> Search  only  the  given  manual sections.  list is a colon- or
> comma-separated list of sections.  If an entry  in  list  is  a
> simple section, for example "3", then the displayed list of descriptions will include pages in sections "3",  "3perl",  "3x",
> and  so on; while if an entry in list has an extension, for example "3perl", then the list will only include  pages  in  that
> exact part of the manual section.

With other versions of `apropos`, you can `grep` the results:

```
apropos read | grep '(1)'
```

or

```
apropos read | grep -E '\((1|8))'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It turns out the `apropos` shipping with macOS doesn't have any option whatsoever... and here I was wondering if I was missing something super obvious.

Comment: Ah, right, so my assumption is wrong ;-).